# How to view Selenium Side runner Command Line (selenium-side-runner) Test Suite results in Azure DevOps Release pipeline under the Test tab

Tags: azure, selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am using the Selenium .side file to perform some tests using **selenium-side-runner** in Command Line on Azure DevOps Release Pipeline. I wanted to check if we can get the test suite result output in the Tests tab on the release summary section, helping us check the results output without opening the log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  You need to specify a command line to point a directory where the selenium-side-runner outputs  the test result to and the format of the output.

For example: selenium-side-runner `--output-directory="<yourfolder>" --output-format=junit`

In the above scripts:

1.output-directory should be a folder in your agent

2.junit is the normal output format

Then, you should add Publish Test Result task

[image]

and do some settings

[image]

The Search  folder should be correspond with the output-directory defined above.

After all, save and run, you will see the output result in the Tests tab.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution  @jaidm. I have an issue that it showed a warning "No test result files matching **/TEST-*.xml were found." and never showed any output. Are we missing the file name at the command prompt?

Comment: Just realised that the XML file bears the name of the .side file. So if the side file is sample.side then the XML file will be sample.xml

Comment: @Haresh Shah If the above solution solve your issue, could you mark my reply as answer? This will help others who will face the same issue in the future, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all of this. I am trying use the Selenium .side file to perform some tests using selenium-side-runner in Command Line on Azure DevOps Release Pipeline also.  When the command line step executes, it cannot load the .side file for some reason. Where do I need to put the .side file? Does it need to be in a folder in the repos with the project and (Angular) so that the deploy process picks it up and deploy it to the target server?

Comment: The solution is not working at all from powershell or cmd line, it's not generate anything in folder, I am using latest selenium side runner 4a alpha